# Word for something being controlled?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that is the counter part to "controller". So far, the closest I can think of is "controllee", but that means something else. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe the control and the response

Comment: _controlee_ (in analogy to _employee_) sounds fine to me; I'm not aware of any alternative meaning.

Comment: Depending on what you're controlled by, *possessed* is a possibility.

Comment: In what context, please? Can you give a sample sentence?

Comment: in many cases, ***the device*** is what is being controlled.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of possible answers to this, depending on the context. If we're talking about people, ***puppet*** is a good term for someone being controlled by someone else. This is especially appropriate when the control isn't obvious, so the puppet master is controlling things "behind the scenes".

From a technical standpoint, I've also seen the word ***slave*** to refer to a machine or computer that is being controlled by another machine or computer. The commands are issued by the *master* computer, and carried out by the slave(s).